# Prism 6.3.0 PrismApplication doesn't have OnInitialized nor RegisterTypes

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using Prism 6.3.0

I trying to use the following code but i'm getting the following errors.

'Application' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

'App.OnInitialized()': no suitable method found to override

'App.RegisterTypes()': no suitable method found to override

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: move your edit to an answer and accept it, so people see it's an actual answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that the XAML file should have been like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Unity;assembly=Prism.Unity.Forms"
                        x:Class="Intro.App">
    <Application.Resources>

        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->

    </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```